# Loading .csv at runtime in Unreal 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm working in unreal and I'm trying to import a .csv asset as a data table at run time. This is my function below and it works for assets that are already imported into unreal but not for new assets.

```
Imported Data Path = DataTable'/Game/Blueprints/Data/ImportedData.ImportedData'
```

It doesn't work when I point it at the new file in the same folder it returns nothing

```
New Data Pathpath = DataTable'/Game/Blueprints/Data/NewData.csv'(or NewData.NewData)
```

I feel like I am missing a step, like defining the new files structure or the cast is failing because it isn't a `UDataTable` yet. Any suggestions?

```
UDataTable * UUlyssesBPFunctions::LoadTableByPath(FName Path, bool& result)
{
    result = false;

    if (Path == NAME_None) return NULL;

        UDataTable* LoadedTable = Cast<UDataTable>(StaticLoadObject(UDataTable::StaticClass(), NULL, *Path.ToString()));

    return LoadedTable;
}
```

Comment: Most assets cannot easily be created at runtime. UE4 has the assets especially because it does not want the developers to deal with system path data files at runtime, but can keep everything inside the packed engine content.
Why not just read the file with a normal C++ file reader? CSV really is not a hard format to parse.

Comment: Yeah ultimately thats the answer i got off the unreal forums. Why didn't I just do it? Because I'm a noob :P
 I'll probably do it tonight. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this answer is a bit late for your question but it may benefit others as it benefitted me today.

Rama has a free blueprint function library of over 120+ custom blueprint nodes; one of which is "Save String file to Text". You just provide the Absolute path, the name of the file(including the file format. In this case, .csv) and the string to save and boom, it works.

I'll link down the plugin

https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/4014-39-rama-s-extra-blueprint-nodes-for-you-as-a-plugin-no-c-required?3851-(39)-Rama-s-Extra-Blueprint-Nodes-for-You-as-a-Plugin-No-C-Required!=